# I am trying to insert html form data in database through php but it's not happening

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, forms

I am trying to insert html form data in database through php.
  I am  unable to insert html form data into  database , i donot know , what i am doing wrong in my code?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'mydb';
$con=mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password,$dbname);
if (!$con) 
{
    echo "connection failed";
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 $name = $_POST['username'];
 $pass = $_POST['password'];
$sql="insert into mytable1 (name,password) VALUES ('$name', '$pass')";
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        echo "DATA IS INSERTED INTO DATABASE";
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SignUpform.com</title>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="div1">
            <div id="div2">
                <h1>Sign up Form</h1>
            </div>
           <form action="" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Signup form ceredentials</legend>
                 <p id="p1">Name:</p>    
                <input id="text1" type="text" placeholder="Enter username" name="username">
                 <p id="p2">Password:</p>
                <input id="pass1" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password">
                <p id="email">Email:</p>
                <input id="emailtextfld" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email">
                <p id="company">Company Name:</p>
                <input id="companytextfld" type="text" placeholder="Company name" name="company">
                <input id="donebtn" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">

            </fieldset>
           </form> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my database
[image]

The structure of my database table:
[image]

Comment: Do you get `DATA IS INSERTED INTO DATABASE`? You are open to SQL injections, parameterize your queries. Your passwords should be hashed.

Comment: no i am not getting this message "Data is inserted into database" @chris85

Comment: So what does happen, nothing is displayed? Can you put `else`s on your conditional to see if either are failing?

Comment: yeah you are right , nothing is displayed when i press "submit button" and when i put else block i got this error message "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp64\www\html\phpfile.php on line 22
" @chris85

Comment: sorry i forgot to put ";" at the end of the else block message so that is why i was getting that error message.After putting else block i got message "Data is not inserted into database"@chris85

Comment: Try putting `echo mysqli_error($con)` in the `else` block to see what the error is.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: A lot of problems can be detected and resolved by [enabling exceptions in `mysqli`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578243/turning-query-errors-to-exceptions-in-mysqli) so mistakes aren't easily ignored.

Comment: after using `echo mysqli_error($con)` in the `else` block i got this message `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''mytable1' ('name','password') VALUES ([], [])' at line 1` @JoelH.

Comment: Are you using the same query that's posted in the question? That error appears to be because of the single quotes. Try using the original query: `$sql="insert into mytable1 (name,password) VALUES ('$name', '$pass')";`.

Comment: The error message is not formatted like the query you provided here. Are you quoting the tables/columns? Why are the values arrays?

Comment: when i try this query `$sql="insert into mytable1 (name,password) VALUES ('$name', '$pass')"; ` it says `mytable1 is read only` @Joel H.

Comment: `(name,password)` these are the table columns @chris85

Comment: If you run it in phpmyadmin is it read only as well? Are you using the same user?

Comment: yeah i am using the same user "root" @chris85

Comment: and the behavior differs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153833/discussion-between-mcolo-and-chris85).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your storage engine of your database from:

`ENGINE=MRG_MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;`

to

```
ENGINE=innoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

From my point of view it's happening just because of "Engine error".So after changing your storage engine of your database , i hope it will work for you inshallah.

Comment: After changing storage engine of my database , it's working fine now and the problem of insertion of data in database is solved now.@Shahab Khan

Answer (score 2):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$name = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$sql="insert into mytable1 (name,password) VALUES ('$name', '$pass')";

$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if($query)
{
echo "<h4 style='color:green'>Inserted Successfully.</h4>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<h4 style='color:red'>Faild.</h4>";
    }
}
?>
```

Try this solution.

Comment: I have tried this but it says "failed" @Prakhar Sood

Comment: So there is something wrong with your insert query. Try to echo the values of username and password, check whether you are even getting the values through the form or not.

Comment: Yes i have echo the values of username and password and it's getting the values through html form @Prakhar Sood

Answer (score 1):

You need to give form action like this

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
```

add this to check connection

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```

Comment: I have tried this  `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>`.  but its still not inserting data in database @Shibon

Comment: After putting this  { echo "reached"; } inside if block it says "reached" @Shibon

Comment: `action` is not required.